# How to use box-api to get the Shared item?

Tags: box-api

Can I have a example of how to use the box-api V2 for getting the shared item details using shared link api.

For example, if the folder is shared for public

```
1. Do I need use authorization in calling the API get the folder details ?
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to check out the documentation for generating shared links (http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-create-a-shared-link-for-a-file) and getting information about files and folders.

If you have access to the file, you can 'Get Information About a File' to determine if the shared link is enabled or not. It will be Null if no, provide a web URL or download URL if it's enabled, as well as if it's a 'Open,' 'Company,' or 'Collaborators Only' link.

If you don't own or have access to the file but do have a shared link to it, though, you might also want to check out this documentation.
http://developers.box.com/using-shared-items/